# Android Data binding : Cannot resolve symbol setContentView

Tags: android, data-binding

The error says:  Cannot resolve setContentView for DataBinding.

I tried to fix this issue like here [Android Data binding : Cannot resolve symbol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32815608/android-data-binding-cannot-resolve-symbol) but nothing happens.

I tried to invalidate and restart studio.
   I tried to clean and rebuild project

Nothing happens. I searched and other articles and say the same thing.

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import com.android.example.applicationtest.databinding.ActivityMainBinding;
import android.databinding.DataBindingUtil;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ActivityMainBinding mBinding;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActivityMainBinding mBinding = new DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);


}
}



apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.android.example.applicationtest"
    minSdkVersion 19
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
dataBinding {
    enabled = true
}
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to write `new` for DataBindingUtil.

You just need to write `DataBindingUtil.setContentView()`

This is because `setContentView()` is a static method of DataBindingUtil.

Comment: I have posted a question and one of the answers told me about the `dataBinding` but I am facing an issue with it kindly check the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73494115/6854117)?

Answer (score 1):

```
use this code 

   ActivityMainBinding  _mainBinding=DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);

//---------------

remove  "new"
```

Comment: your are use new keyword on this code  ActivityMainBinding mBinding = new DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this,R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: if you are facing any other problem let me know. Thank you

Comment: I actually have: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51340516/android-binding-type-associated-with-an-element-type-variable-must-not-conta